# dynamic table in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-tables

I am trying to create dynamic table in js.

```
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);
   for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
     {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);

        for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {

        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '75';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item(i).medicine_name));
        tr.appendChild(td); 
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item(i).tm_1));
        tr.appendChild(td); 
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item(i).tm_2));
        tr.appendChild(td); 
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item(i).tm_3));
        tr.appendChild(td); 
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item(i).dosage));
        tr.appendChild(td); 
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item(i).diagnosis));
        tr.appendChild(td); 
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item(i).instructions));
        tr.appendChild(td); 

        }


     }
         myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

When I execute this code, 7 rows will be created with all the items together. I want to insert each of the data in seperate columns. How can I do it? I want medicine_name to be in one column. tm_1 to be in another and so on.

**The rows will be decided based on *results.rows.length* value and the number of columns is 7
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Totally you have 7 columns and 7 rows.So in first text node `td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item((i*7) + 0).medicine_name));` And in second text node use
`td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results.rows.item((i*7) + 1).tm_1));` and so on...

Comment: No.. Actually the number of rows vary. I have seven columns only.

Comment: actually u getting the length of the rows using `results.rows.length`. so what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var html = "";
            html += "<tr>";    
            html += "<td>" + results[i].MedicineName + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].tm_1+ "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].tm_2+ "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].dosage+ "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].diagnosis+ "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].instructions+ "</td>";          
            html += "</tr>";
            $('#myTableDiv').append(html);
        }
```

Comment: why have you posted two diff answers ? and moreover the way you have given both the answers doesn't serve the purpose until and unless you explain your code - what it does and which part of the code is key

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var results = getResults();
        createTable(results);

    });
    function createTable(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var html = "";
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].MedicineName + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].tm_1 + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].tm_2 + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].dosage + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].diagnosis + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + results[i].instructions + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            $('#myTableDiv').append(html);
        }
    }
    function getResults() {
        var Results = new Array(0);

        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            var data = new medicine;
            data.MedicineName = "Medicine" + j;
            data.tm_1 = "tm1" + j;
            data.tm_2 = "tm2" + j;
            data.dosage = "tm3" + j;
            data.diagnosis = "tm4" + j;
            data.instructions = "tm5" + j;        
            Results.push(data);
        }
        return Results;
    };
    function medicine() {
        var MedicineName = new String();     
        var tm_1 = new String();
        var tm_2 = new String();
        var dosage = new String();
        var diagnosis = new String();
        var instructions = new String();
    }
</script>
```